# Elements are not showing while being animated (CSS)

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I have 135 HTML videos (stopped) inside a container. I am animating the container using CSS, scaling it and repositioning it.

While the animation is taking place, most of the videos are not showing up. As soon as the animation is finished the videos are then shown.

I am using `transform: scale3d() translate3d()` to perform the animation.

I noticed that when I don't use `transform` and I instead `transition` the `width`, `height`, `top` and `left` the problem is less prominent.

It looks like while a `transform` animation is happening, the browser captures what is visible in the viewport at the ***start*** of the animation and ignores the rest for the ***duration*** of the animation. And as soon as the animation finishes, the browser then renders the rest.

**Question:** Is there a way to fix this and keep ***all*** video elements rendered at all times ***while*** the animation is taking place?

I'm also providing a jsfiddle for a better preview of the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/r8qh0wsc/2/show

Hit `s` to start the animation after you see the first video load on your screen.

**Set your window size to 1440x764** to test.

```js
const VIDEO_URL = 'https://test-videos.co.uk/vids/bigbuckbunny/mp4/h264/720/Big_Buck_Bunny_720_10s_1MB.mp4'

const VIDEOS_CONTAINER = document.getElementById('videos')
const VIDEOS_TO_ADD = 135

let videosAdded = 0
let croppers = []

while (videosAdded < VIDEOS_TO_ADD) {
  let cropper = document.createElement('div')
  cropper.classList.add('loop-cropper')

  if (videosAdded === 50) {
    cropper.id = 'main-loop'
  }

  let video = document.createElement('video')
  video.classList.add('loop')
  video.width = 1280
  video.height = 720

  let source = document.createElement('source')
  source.src = VIDEO_URL
  source.type = 'video/mp4'

  video.appendChild(source)
  cropper.appendChild(video)
  croppers.push(cropper)
  VIDEOS_CONTAINER.appendChild(cropper)

  videosAdded++
}

document.body.addEventListener('keydown', async ({ which }) => {
  if (which === 83) { // s = small
    croppers.forEach((cropper) => {
      cropper.style.opacity = 1
    })

    setTimeout(() => {
      VIDEOS_CONTAINER.classList.add('small')
    }, 1000)
  }
})
```

```css
@keyframes small {
  0% {
    transform: scale3d(2.1, 2.1, 1) translate3d(-744px, -669px, 0);
  }

  100% {
    transform: scale3d(0.145, 0.145, 1) translate3d(-30830px, -18852px, 0);
  }
}

.loop-cropper {
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  height: 690px;
  width: 690px;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
}

.loop-cropper video {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -79px;
  height: 720px;
  width: 1280px;
}

#main-loop{
  opacity: 1;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 13px solid red;
}

#videos {
  position: absolute;
  width: 10350px;
  height: 6210px;
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform: scale3d(2.1, 2.1, 1) translate3d(-744px, -669px, 0);
}

#videos.small {
  animation-name: small;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="videos">

</div>
```

Comment: You want to animate 123 videos at the same time? That seems problematic to start with. What exactly are you hoping to achieve?

Comment: 135 to be exact :) They will never play simultaneously. During the animation, more importantly, they will all remain paused. My issue is with them being hidden during the css animation. If you replace each video with an <img> the same issue will occur most likely. It looks like a browser/CSS *transform* limitation, unrelated to the fact that this is a video element and not e.g. an <img>. I'm wondering whether there is a way around it or whether it is inevitable. If I replace scale3d/translate3d and work with top/left/width/height the issue is less prominent but still there.

Comment: I can't get your example working to be honest... :( But yeah it seems like you use some crazy high transform values. Maybe you can create a simpler jsfiddle with only images? And still I think loading 135 videos is not a good idea... :)

Comment: If you hit `s` after you the video preview load on your screen, then the animation happens and if you wit ~7-10 seconds you'll see the final result eventually (on a 1440x764 window). But yes I think the given the number of videos there is no way around it unfortunately. But there is no other way since this is an online art project. More of a one-off presentation. Nothing for the user to interact with or be efficient in the long run.

Comment: Could you describe what the animation should look like? I can't follow what is to happen to each of the videos.

Comment: There are 135 video elements inside a container. One of them has a red border around it. The animation starts off with the container scaled-up and positioned so that the video with the red border is centered on your window (if your window is 1440x764). When you hit `s` the whole of the container is scaled down and repositioned so that at the end of the animation you see the whole of the container and all of the videos inside it on your 1440x764 window. The animation is "correct". The problem is that *during* the animation not all videos are rendered, even though they should.